# How can I draw both Texture2Ds thats in a list in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I have a Texture2D list called blockTexture  that has 2 elements in it.

I use the following line to draw the first element

```
foreach (Vector2 blockPosition in blockPositions)
 spriteBatch.Draw(blockTexture[0], blockPosition, Color.White);
```

The blockPosition list is to display the elements in random positions

I can I get it to draw both of the elements at once?

If I change the blockTexture[0] to blockTexture[1] it draws the second element. But I need it to draw both at the same time.

How can I do this?

Edit:

```
Texture2D personTexture;
// The images will be drawn with this SpriteBatch
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
// Person 
Vector2 personPosition;
const int PersonMoveSpeed = 5;

List<Vector2> blockPositions = new List<Vector2>();
float BlockSpawnProbability = 0.01f;
const int BlockFallSpeed = 2;

List<Texture2D> blockTexture = new List<Texture2D>();

Random random = new Random();
```

protected override void LoadContent()
        {

```
        blockTexture.Add(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Block"));
        blockTexture.Add(Content.Load<Texture2D>("right"));

        // Load textures
      // blockTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Block");
       personTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Person");
       //rightTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Right");

        //Load the score font
        font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("gameFont");

        // Create a sprite batch to draw those textures
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(graphics.GraphicsDevice);
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Get input
        KeyboardState keyboard = Keyboard.GetState();
        GamePadState gamePad = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);

        // Spawn new falling blocks 
        if (random.NextDouble() < BlockSpawnProbability)
        {
            float x = (float)random.NextDouble() * (Window.ClientBounds.Width - blockTexture[0].Width);
            blockPositions.Add(new Vector2(x, -blockTexture[0].Height));
       }

        // Get the bounding rectangle of the person
        Rectangle personRectangle =
            new Rectangle((int)personPosition.X, (int)personPosition.Y,
            personTexture.Width, personTexture.Height);

        // Update each block
        personHit = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < blockPositions.Count; i++)
        {
            // Animate this block falling
            blockPositions[i] =
                new Vector2(blockPositions[i].X, blockPositions[i].Y + BlockFallSpeed);

             // Get the bounding rectangle of this block
                Rectangle sprite =
                    new Rectangle((int)blockPositions[i].X, (int)blockPositions[i].Y,
                    blockTexture[0].Width, blockTexture[0].Height);


                // check collision with person
                if (personRectangle.Intersects(sprite))
                    personHit = true;
                // Remove this block if it have fallen off the screen
                if ((blockPositions[i].Y > Window.ClientBounds.Height))
                {
                    blockPositions.RemoveAt(i);
                    // When removing a block, the next block will have the same index
                    // as the current block. Decrement i to prevent skipping a block.
                    i--;
                }
            }

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }
```

and in the draw section:

```
foreach (Vector2 blockPosition in blockPositions)
            {
                //foreach (Texture2D blocktexture in blockTexture)
               //spriteBatch.Draw(blockTexture[1], blockPosition, Color.White);
                for (int i = 0; i < blockPositions.Count; i++ )
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(blockTexture[i], blockPositions[i], Color.White);


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly drawing both in sequence within your foreach loop:

```
foreach (Vector2 blockPosition in blockPositions)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(blockTexture[0], blockPosition, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.Draw(blockTexture[1], blockPosition, Color.White);
}
```

Or do you mean that you want to draw `blockTexture[0]` at `blockPositions[0]` and `blockTexture[1]` at `blockPositions[1]`?  In that case:

```
for (int i = 0; i < blockPositions.Length; i++)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(blockTexture[i], blockPositions[i], Color.White);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, 
But in that case it only draws the element that's on the bottom which is blockTexture[1].

Comment: I just saw your edit.. 
When this runs it does actually work until both the objects come until the end of the screen, then new ones start falling, and it stops running the game gives an error saying Argument Out Of Range Exception..
Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: I'd have to see more of your code to debug that problem.

Comment: I think it happens because blockPositions and blockTexture are not the same size. I wrote some parts of the code.. I would really appreciate if you can help me sort this problem.. I just need these 2 different objects to fall in different positions..

Comment: That would do it, all right.  The second code block will crash if `blockTexture` is shorter than `blockPositions`.